# On a characterization of compact operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space of infinite dimension  and $\{α_n \}$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R$. 
Let $\{e_n : n ∈ \Bbb N\}$ and $\{ e_n' : n ∈ \Bbb N\}$ be two orthonormal sets in $H$.

Let $T : H → H$ defined by $T (x) = \sum_{n∈\Bbb N}α_n (x, e_n ) e_n'$

Prove that $T$ is a compact operator iff $α_n → 0$.

I tried to use Bessel's inequality witout success and I don't see how to proceed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One approach is to note that $TT^*$ is a diagonal operator, i.e.
$$
TT^* = \sum_n \alpha_n^2 (x,e_n)e_n
$$
and that $T$ is compact if and only if $TT^*$ is compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha_n$ fails to converge to zero, then there exists a subsequence $(x_n)$ of $(e_n)$ such that $Tx_n$ has no convergent subsequence.  We can build this sequence by selecting indices $n_k$ such that $\inf_k |\alpha_{n_k}| > 0$.

On the other hand, if $\alpha_n \to 0$, then $T$ is a limit (in operator norm) of finite-rank operators, and is therefore compact.  In particular, we have
$$
T = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N \alpha_n (x,e_n)e_n'.
$$